# Why can't I easily manage contact images in Drupal Views any more?

Tags: drupal-views, contact-image

I'm updating an old D6/Civi site to D7. It includes some Drupal Views that display listings of contacts along with the contact image (in our case we're working with organisational contact records and using the contact image field to store a logo.

This just worked on the D6 site, where Views simply provided the raw image URL in [image_URL] and I was able to rewrite it in the View and so control the size of the rendered image to suit the view.

In D7 now this looks totally broken. I can get the view to display the image, but [image_URL] now includes the `img` tag and everything, so I can't just get the raw URL any more and rewrite it.

There appear to be other questions here referring to the same issue, and a number of issues in Jira, but i can't find anything that provides a decent workable solution.

Has anyone got this resolved, and if so, how?

Comment: hmm. pretty sure i spelt out what needs putting in the views link. if i spot a site we have this i will post back.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the **Output the image URL only** option as shown below?

[image: Output the image URL only]

Comment: That looks ideal, but I don't see the "output the image URL only" option in my site. I'll check to ensure that everything is up to date.

Comment: I'm running Civi 4.6.30 at the moment. I'm guessing this feature isn't available in 4.6.x? I will be updating to 4.7 after we've completed the current work programme on the site, so it is at least useful to know that a fix is waiting.

Comment: I tested it on 4.7. I suppose it was added with https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17638 .So maybe you can apply this patch on 4.6.